# Cannot able to find output for Getters and setters in Map <LinkedHashMap>?

Tags: java, object, getter-setter, encapsulation, linkedhashmap

I have created 2 classes [Banking and Website]
In banking class I have created Getters and setters for username and password data
In  Website class I have created LinkedHashMap to get the output. But when I run/compile the program i get the output in Memory codes. Please help me on this issue.

**Code for Class Banking :**

```
package org.encap;

public class Banking {
    private int username;
    private String password;
    public int getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(int username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**Code for Class Website :**

```
package org.encap;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
 
public class Website {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banking a=new Banking();
        a.setUsername(111);
        a.setPassword("Password");
        //System.out.println(a.getUsername());
        //System.out.println(a.getPassword());
 
        Banking b=new Banking();
        b.setPassword("Password2");
        b.setUsername(222);
        //System.out.println(b.getUsername());
        //System.out.println(b.getPassword());

        //user defined Map
        Map<Integer, Banking> mp=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mp.put(1, a);
        mp.put(2, b);
        System.out.println(mp.get(1));
        System.out.println(mp.get(2));
        System.out.println(mp.values());
        System.out.println(mp.entrySet());
    }
}
```

**Output when I run the program :**

```
org.encap.Banking@7852e922
org.encap.Banking@4e25154f
[org.encap.Banking@7852e922, org.encap.Banking@4e25154f]
[1=org.encap.Banking@7852e922, 2=org.encap.Banking@4e25154f]
```

[Code and output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Rek.png)

I am not getting the output in String and Numbers .. Im getting only memory vales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to print the object of Class Banking by iterating the LinkedHashMap

In order to print the content of Banking class object, implement the toString method of the object class in Banking class in the preferred format